# Permission Base Authorize in Asp .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to use the permission base system in Asp .NET Core . Do you know a source that teaches this in the best way, or do you know a better system than permission base?

Comment: I think you want authentication.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-and-authorization-in-aspnet-web-api?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng authentication solves the problem of identifying who the user is. Authorization knows who the user is and solves the problem whether this user is permitted to do the action.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for "Authorization".

See the claims authorization for .NET core
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-6.0 .

A claim can be "Admin" , "SuperUser" etc.